# Access query to excel 2010 to create a graph via vba

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

After an extensive search I have been unable to find any information on this that I could understand. there are numerous examples, but these are all for access 2003, and these do not work in access 2010.

I need to run a vba code that will export the results of a query (QryTotalSale) to excel 2010 and automatically create a bar chart of the data and show this over the database that is running.

If anyone could give me some advise then I would greatly appreciate it, or even a link to a valid resource that will work in 2010.

So far I can get excel to open, and display the results of the query in question.

To make it more difficult I really need the query to open a specific excel file, which will be on a folder on the desktop and every time the button is pressed to run the VBA, a new page should be added to the excel workbook, and the new graph be shown, and saved into the spreadsheet, so that at a later date the entire excel file can be viewed.

I have the below code, but it does not work. the bit about ranges would work in excel, but access does not seem to recognise range ( which does not really suprise me as it does not really work with ranges to my knowledge.)

My second thought was to have the first two doCmd's run, then have the next bit be forced to auto run in the excel file.

```
Private Sub SalesImage_Click()

DoCmd.OpenQuery "QryTotalSale"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel


          Dim myRange as range
                    Set myRange = B2 * C30
                                            Charts.Add
                                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange, _
        PlotBy:=xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
End Sub
```

I found a adodb code type thing for the 2003 versions of access and excel,  but could not get this to work. half of the options no longer seem to be recognised by access...

I am a long way off and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some notes. I have used late binding, so you do not need to set a reference to the Excel library, however, I have included notes on the types.

```
Dim xl As Object ''Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object ''Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Object ''Excel.Worksheet
Dim ch As Object ''Excel.Chart
Dim myRange As Object

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

sExcelWB = "z:\docs\testchart.xls"

''This will overwrite any previous run of this query to this workbook
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Query1", _
      sExcelWB, True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)

''Sheets are named with the Access query name
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Query1")
Set ch = xl.Charts.Add
ch.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

xl.Visible = True
xl.UserControl = True
''Still not saved
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great start.

two things I cant get....

where you have used "query1" I renamed this to the query I want to use, but access cannot find it? I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Is it possible to use the date function in the naming of the worksheet?

Comment: If Access says it cannot find you query, check your spelling. The easiest thing would be to rename the sheet with the current date after it has been created. Do not use - or /, call the sheet, say `2012Apr21`