# How to open an Excel workbook from Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I currently have a string in Microsoft Access that is delegating functions to an external Application.

I have gotten so far as to copying a set of data from the external application.

I want to paste this into an excel workbook that is not open but exists. C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop KDNR.xlsx

how can I integrate this function into my sub procedure?

Thank you in advance

I attempted simply writing

```
Dim x as Workbook 

set x = Workbooks.Open (" workbook name ")
```

Howoever, i got the compile error "user defined type not defined"

when i just write

```
Workbooks.Open (" workbook name ")
```

i get the compile error

> "variable not defined"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609086/8422953

Comment: Did you add an Excel reference to MS Access? It's not going to know what a workbook is if you don't.

Comment: `Dim wb as object` and `set wb = GetObject("c:\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx")`. Review my answer here for your options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269979/vb-net-add-workbook-to-running-excel-instance/74270544#74270544

Answer (score 2):

### Use Excel From Access

- This is a basic example of how to work with Excel from Access.
- It opens a new instance of Excel (whether Excel is open or not), opens the workbook, writes the string `Test` to cell `A1` of worksheet `Sheet1`, saves and closes the workbook, and finally quits the Excel instance.

```vb
' If you haven't already, create a reference to
' "Tools->References->Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library"!

Sub Test()
    
    Dim DestinationFilePath As String
    DestinationFilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\DeskTop\KDNR.xlsx"
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True ' out-comment when done developing; default is 'False'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(DestinationFilePath)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Test"
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    xlApp.Quit
        
End Sub
```